# Ajax textarea save error

Tags: javascript, json, jquery

I try to do ajax edit textarea. When I click "edit" button I get textarea with text to edit and when save textarea disappear and edited text with all 
 must appeaer in

```
    jQuery('.photocont #commeditCont').animate({opacity: 0}, timer, function()
    {
        if (id == 'commedit') jQuery(this).html('<textarea>'+jQuery(this).html().replace(/<br>/gi,"\n")+'</textarea>');
        else if (id == 'commsave') {

            var link = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + 'picture_edit';

            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: link,
                data: { image : image, description : jQuery(this).html(jQuery(this).find('textarea').val()) },
                dataType: "json",
                context: this,
                success: function(data) {
                    jQuery(this).html(jQuery(this).find('textarea').val().replace(/\n/g,"<br>"));
                },
                error:function (xhr){
                    if (xhr.status == 401) {
                        window.location.href = link;
                    }
                }
            });

        }
});
```

in ajax `success: function` I try to get text from textarea and replace with new my div. Unfortunately I get error

```
NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS: Could not convert JavaScript argument

...a[2]||k.error(a[0]),a[2]=a[2].replace(/^\+|\s*/g,"");var b=/(-?)(\d*)(?:n([+\-]?...

jquery....min.js (line 16)

TypeError: jQuery(this).find("textarea").val() is undefined 

jQuery(this).html(jQuery(this).find('textarea').val().replace(/\n/g,"<br>"));
```

Error come from console.

Answer (score 0):

`this` is out of scope in the success function and therefore it is undefined. Try caching this and using that instead, like the following:

```
jQuery('.photocont #commeditCont').animate({opacity: 0}, timer, function() {
    if ( id == 'commedit' ) {
        jQuery(this).html('<textarea>' + jQuery(this).html().replace(/<br>/gi, "\n") + '</textarea>');
    }
    else if ( id == 'commsave' ) {

        var link = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + 'picture_edit',
            self = this;

        jQuery.ajax({
            type    : "POST",
            url     : link,
            data    : { image: image, description: jQuery(this).html(jQuery(this).find('textarea').val()) },
            dataType: "json",
            context : this,
            success : function( data ) {
                jQuery(self).html(jQuery(self).find('textarea').val().replace(/\n/g, "<br>"));
            },
            error   : function( xhr ) {
                if ( xhr.status == 401 ) {
                    window.location.href = link;
                }
            }
        });

    }
});
```

Comment: ok, we can change this for '.photocont #commeditCont' and there will not be a undefined error but I still have NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS: Could not convert JavaScript argument

Comment: @ViktorsGolubevs Hard to debug without you making a jsfiddle or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Look at what you are doing here

```
description: jQuery(this).html(jQuery(this).find('textarea').val())
```

Is that what you want to send to the server? I think you wanted the text

The real issueis the fact your this is in the wrong scope in the callback

```
           success: function(data) {
                jQuery(this).html(jQuery(this).find('textarea').val().replace(/\n/g,"<br>"));
            },
```

If you would have not kept on using `jQuery(this)` over and over, there would not have been a problem. You need to maintain scope.

```
jQuery('.photocont #commeditCont').animate({
    opacity: 0
}, timer, function () {
    var div = jQuery(this);
    if (id == 'commedit') div.html('<textarea>' + div.html().replace(/<br>/gi, "\n") + '</textarea>');
    else if (id == 'commsave') {

        var link = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + 'picture_edit';

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: link,
            data: {
                image: image,
                description: div.html(jQuery(this).find('textarea').val()) //I still think this is not right
            },
            dataType: "json",
            context: this,
            success: function (data) {
                div.html(div.find('textarea').val().replace(/\n/g, "<br>"));
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                if (xhr.status == 401) {
                    window.location.href = link;
                }
            }
        });

    }
});
```

Comment: I try with this line send text with all <br> element

Comment: I know I helped you yesterday!

Comment: What is description supposed to be?

Comment: description : it is text from textarea with all &nbsp; and <br> then I safe it in data base and when reload page  SQL show it in div

Comment: jQuery(this).find('textarea').val() = for example (1<br>2<br>3<br>)

Comment: look what it is doing, what you showed and what that line is doing are two totally different things

Comment: alert(jQuery(this).html(jQuery(this).find('textarea').val()));   <--- returned like what is in my example above